# Google maps v3 driving directions with a clickable route / infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm plotting driving directions on google map using the v3 api.

I'd like to add a listener so that if someone clicks on any point of the route that I can open an infowindow.

I can do this with a polyline:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapEntry, 'click', function (e) {
    infowindow.position = e.latLng;
    infowindow.open(map);
});
```

I've tried to attach the click event to the following items in the directions response:

```
response.route[0].overview_path
response.route[0].overview_polyline
response.route[0].overview_polyline.points
```

But no luck. Can't even hit the click event. Any ideas?

Comment: It would help with some more code.. how did you try to add the click events? Just by creating a new google.maps.Polyline?

Comment: No, this is a direction response. I just added the example of how simple it is to attach a click listener to a polyline, which a direction response should mimic...but doesn't seem to.

Comment: Ok, but can´t you just create a new Polyline with the data from the response and add the click event to that? Not really a nice solution but could be worth a try maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever try the solution below? It is a trigger function of Google Maps, maybe it can help you..

```
google.maps.event.trigger(mapEntry, 'click', function(){
//do other things
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, it works for me
After calling the `modirectionsDisplay.setDirections(response);`
call

```
   setTimeout(function () {
       try {
           modirectionsDisplay.j.polylines.forEach(function (polyline) {
                //attach event listener
            });
       } catch (e) {
           alert(e);
       }
   }, 200);
```

It's not the best development method but it works. Also you must disable the draggable option in DirectionsRenderer.